# Batch Script Reading TXT File

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am looking for a way for a batch script to be able to read a txt file.

Lets say the txt file has a number such as "723121312", and I only put that number in there.

Now from the batch script, I want to be able to store that number as a variable, `%update_id%`.

The batch script will run a program like so:

```
call gmpublish.exe update -addon %folder%\*.gma -id %update_id% -changes %update_changes%
```

The other two variables don't matter, as I already made those automatic.

It will store inside the batch script so the program would run like so:

```
call gmpublish.exe update -addon %folder%\*.gma -id %723121312% -changes %update_changes%
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want something like:

```
FOR /F %%i IN (file.txt) DO call gmpublish.exe update -addon %folder%\*.gma -id %%i -changes %update_changes%
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's only one line to be stored, it's as simple as:

```
REM writing to file:
>file.txt echo 1234567
REM reading from file:
<file.txt set /p "var="
echo %var%
```

if there are more lines, `for /f` (as in razor's answer) is the better way.